# PIco W: is there a way to detect if usb power is connected in micropython?

Tags: gpio, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

I am trying to detect (ideally fire an interrupt) when a usb host is connected and supplies 5v. (in this design i have a separate "always on" Vsys supplied from another source).

According to the schematics in https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/picow/pico-w-datasheet.pdf it would be possible to know this by reading the state of the WL_GPOI2 pin. Unfortunately this pin is actually located on the CYW43439 wifi chip.

[image: GPIO on CYW43]

The green led on the board (connected to WL_GPOI0) is trivially accessible by using the below so it seems possible to get to the GPIO on the wifi chip.

```
from machine import Pin

led = Pin("LED", Pin.OUT)
```

Is there a way of reading the WL_GPOI2 pin or otherwise finding out if a usb cable is connected?
ideal would be to fire an interrupt, but polling a status would also work.

Comment: Why wouldn't `gpio_get (WL_GPOI2)` work? If the connector is attached `vbus` should be HIGH. It is dioded with a Schotty diode `D1` which will prevent `vsys` feedback into `vbus`, so simply checking the state of `WL_GPOI2` should work. I haven't tried, but based on the schematic, that is what you would want to do.

Comment: @david: correct, I am attempting to read the state of WL_GPOI2 But from wahjt it looks like to me in (micropython/ports/rp2/boards/PICO_W/mpconfigboard.h etc) GPIO's are only predefined for the main chip, with the "LED" being a special case.  If not, where can the list of predefined "pins" be found?

Comment: Ooh, that's is a question. I don't use python, but the gpio pins have to be defined somewhere. In C, the `WL_..PIN`s are already defined, that is why I anticipated you should be able to get the pin-state using `WL_GPOI2`. I'll have time to look int how the micropython setup handles that in a bit.

Comment: Great! My C /C++ skills are limited to "i did a class at uni in the 90's" so the "looks like" assessment above is very much a "kicks tyres whilst humming" type assessment of the code :)

Comment: I have spent time trying to chase down how micropython references any of the `WL_GPOI..` pins and my google foo has failed me. With C, I can just grep the source files and find the pin definitions, but I have no idea where to begin with micropython. In micropython, you Have the `Pin` class, where `Pin.value[x]` will get or set the pin value (depending on whether `x` is provided), but there is no reference as to what you would use for `WL_GPOI2` or any of the other `WL_GPO...` pins. A micropython wizard will have to help us out here.

Comment: Thank for the effort! I'm going to assume unimplemented in micropython for now and just wire up Vbus(#40)  to pullup one of the other GPIOS.

Comment: My best guess (not knowing how micropython does it) would be `Pin.WL_GPOI2[];` would get the pin-state *IF* mycropython follows the schematic nomenclature. But note -- this is my best GUESS and we really need a micropython wiz to point to where this is actually defined.